# How to stop OS X Lion automatically asking me to join a network

Tags: macos, network

I'm on a school network so I have to sign in before I can use the internet. Before in OS X 10.6 it would just connect me to the network and let me signin on my own. Which I made a script to login for me.) However, now with this new join dialog that pops up asking with the login window, I can't have my script automatically log me in.

So how can I prevent OS X Lion from attempting to join the network? I looked into this and it works like on the iPhone. The computer will try to access http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html and when that fails it will show a pop up window asking for my login.

Comment: Perhaps we could standardize on the terms "Auto-Join" and "Auto-Login" so the joining means making the radio link and login is the credentials to get past the web form?

Answer (score 2):

In System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi you can check or uncheck the "Ask to join new networks". Under "Advanced" you'll also need to uncheck the box next to "Remember networks this computer has joined".

Comment: This is not what I wanted. It used to work in Snow Leopard. The network needs to connect to the wifi, but not attempt to login, like it does in Lion. I'm attaching a photo to explain what I get.